# spark streaming and kafka integration dependency problem

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, sbt, spark-structured-streaming

am trying to write a script that reads data from kafka with spark streaming but when i run "sbt compile" i get this error:

> sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_3:3.5.0

- spark version: 3.5.0
- kafka version: kafka_2.13-3.6.1

any help would be appreciated

if this has anything to do with version compatibility what are the possibe solutions for this problem.

Comment: Show us your `build.sbt` declaration for the dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_3` mentioned in the error isn't a valid version for that package

This is correct for sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "3.5.0"
```

But make sure you have Scala 2.13 installed, not Scala 3, as Spark doesn't support that